# Finding duplicates using HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to find all duplicates in below table.
I know I could use a CTE to wrap query and then syntax would be correct.
I am interested in solution where I would be able to access cnt column directly.
I'd like to use count() over (partition by) clause as well.

```
CREATE TABLE #People
(
ID INT,
[NAME] varchar(50),
AGE INT
)
INSERT INTO #PEOPLE
SELECT 1,'Mark',23
UNION
SELECT 2,'Tomm',23
UNION
SELECT 3,'Ann',26

select * from #People


select [NAME] , AGE, count(1) over (partition by [NAME], AGE) as cnt 
from #People 
having count(cnt) > 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `group by`?

```
select name, age, count(*) as cnt
from #People 
group by name, age
having count(*) > 2
```

If you want *duplicates*, then perhaps the comparison should be:

```
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: The elegant and simple approach is always best :D

Comment: result of this query: Invalid column name 'cnt'.

Comment: Needs to be `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2`. The `HAVING` is processed **before** `SELECT`. [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: to find duplicates i would say wehre COUNT(*)>1 actually

Comment: @DougCoats . . . I adjusted the answer.  The `> 2` was provided by the OP.

Comment: @gordonlinoff yes i know but i was commenting for OP’s learning sake.